# iText 7 how do I generate a Data Matrix code in C#

Tags: c#, barcode, itext7

I want to create a data matrix code with iText 7. However I don't get it working. The Java API for the class provides a method to fetch the image itself but the .NET one doesn't seem to have this one.

How can I generate and get the image for the data matrix code with iText 7?

I allready tried to write my code as PDF but I think I did something wrong here.

```
BarcodeDataMatrix barcode = new BarcodeDataMatrix(artikelnummer);
                
barcode.CreateFormXObject(
    iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.BLACK, 
    new PdfDocument(
        new PdfWriter(
            Path.Combine(GlobalConfig.OutputPfadWK5, $"{artikelnummer}.pdf")
        ), 
    new DocumentProperties())
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked already the [iText 7 C# Barcodes samples](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/tree/develop/itext/itext.samples/itext/samples/sandbox/barcodes) on [iText's GitHub](https://github.com/itext)?

Answer (score 0):

Just placing here the code snip available on the [Repo](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/blob/develop/itext/itext.samples/itext/samples/sandbox/barcodes/BarcodeTypes.cs#L206) (slightly changed):

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, new PageSize(340, 842));
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Barcode Datamatrix"));
BarcodeDataMatrix datamatrix = new BarcodeDataMatrix();
datamatrix.SetCode("My Text");
Image imgDM = new Image(datamatrix.CreateFormXObject(pdfDoc));
doc.Add(imgDM.ScaleToFit(250, 250));
doc.Close();
```